# GitHub Markdown - Add current branch name

Tags: github, branch, markdown, placeholder

Just a short question:

Is it possible to show the current branch name in e.g. README.md automatically with a placeholder or something like that using GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I'm not aware of anything like that within READMEs or any other markdown documents when browsing through the source of your project. And nothing turns up when searching their [help page](https://help.github.com/search/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=readme) either.

However, [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) offers [all sorts of info](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-metadata-on-github-pages/) about the repo the document is associated with. Of course, GitHub Pages is a very different thing than a README file, so that may or may not be helpful to you.